# iPhone - why the status bar is hiding when playing movie using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, statusbar

One good feature in iOS 4 is that we can resize the movie player.
I'm using MPMoviePlayerController to play a video file. I'm resizing the view to show it in half screen only.
When video is being played, the status bar is hiding and it shows white box in place of status bar. When video completes playing, its not showing status bar again.
How to avoid the situation of hiding status bar?